# How to properly display the contents of a post in group conversations?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to display information about the groups a user is in. Specifically I want to load recent posts from conversations in a group.

Calling the API [GET /groups/{id}/threads/{id}/posts/{id}](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/post_get), I get json that has a body property containing the post's html.

The problem arises when a post contains an emoji. They get output like this:

```
<img explicitlogon="group-name@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
     src="cid:5f456809-0c51-4717-a69d-50d6d3c5657b" 
     alt="" 
     id="OWAEmoji518229">
```

So, being in the context of an external web application consuming the Graph API, what is the recommended way to display this? Is there some way to resolve the src to something useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Inline attachments. You should pull attachments of the post and the src CID will match one of the attachment name. You resolve it that way.

Comment: I have checked that after finding [this](https://xomino.com/2016/06/19/where-are-the-mime-embedded-images-in-a-microsoft-graph-rest-api-call/), but sadly the posts do not have attachments (i.e. the "hasAttachments" property is set to "false" and the the route "/attachments" returns an empty array)

Comment: Scratch my earlier comment, i checked the attachments of the wrong post. Thanks for the hint. GET /groups/{id}/threads/{id}/posts/{id}/attachments returns the image data in an attachment.

The "hasAttachments" property is still "false" though, not sure why this is the case.

Comment: HasAttachments property doesn't consider Inline attachments. Only proper attachments.